# FitNesse: HSAC table template scenario + Freemarker template

Tags: fitnesse

Can we use both table template and Freemarker template from `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures` in the same FitNesse wiki table?

Answer (score 0):

A scenario is not the same as a table template even tho they behave similar.

A Freemarker template is a file template that can be used with variables to create json or XML or other files you need in your test. This is in no way similar to table templates.

To start a different fixture from the one you started the script table, use the start command instead of script.

Example:

```
|script|fixture|
|do|stuff|
|start|otherfixture|
|do|more|stuff|
```

So to answer your question, you can use all this in one table.
How to use a scenario vs how to use a table template is another question I am afraid.